# how to configuration of elastic search in magento 2.3 beta?

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.3

I have to install elastic search and set configuration from Magento admin but still got the error when I run the command

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"wrong value for index [false] for field [country_of_manufacture]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"wrong value for index [false] for field [country_of_manufacture]"},"status":400}
```

[image]

Comment: you can information related to elastic search from here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html check this one also https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-conf-files_services-elastic.html

Comment: i already follow this dev.docs but still getting error.

Comment: what version of elastic are you using? The latest version of Elastic that Magento 2.3.0 is compatible with is 5.2.x